# Interface builder problem when Iphone app converted to Universal app

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, interface, interface-builder

I built an iphone app and in one of the views(buit using IB), I put an activity indicator ( little spinner indicating network activity) in the middle. It works fine on my iphone but once I use an Ipad the spinner goes to the to left corner. So the spinner never correspond to the intended location on Ipad no matter where I move it in IB.

Any suggestion to solve this problem? Do I have to rebuild the app specifically for ipad?
Thanks

Comment: Look at the autosizing settings for your spinner in IB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Interface Builder, select the Activity Indicator and open the Size Inspector.
Default shortcut in Xcode 4 is `⌥ ⌘ 5`, icon looks like a ruler.

Second section, on the left, a box labeled "Autosizing". The bars around the outside turn each anchor on or off, and the arrows inside turn autoresizing on/off for either direction (x / y)

With the indicator centered in the view, turn all four anchors on.
Solid red is on, semitransparent is off.